# Хештег в поле ввода

Tags: html, angularjs, hashtag

Здравствуйте, у меня есть проблема.

Нужно реализовать, чтобы в одном поле ввода и тег, и сообщение вводились, а после заносились в массив как два разных объекта

Вот [пример](http://codepen.io/endoneslife/pen/yabwNA?editors=1010), где это реализовано в два поля

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  
    $scope.todoList = [{
      todoText: " " , 
      hashtag: " "   
    }];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.todoList.push({
          hashtag: "#" + $scope.todoHashTag ,
          todoText: $scope.todoMessage  
        });
      
        $scope.todoMessage = "";
        $scope.todoHashTag = "";
      
    };
  
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<h2>Test App</h2>

<form ng-submit="todoAdd()">
  
    <input id="hashTag" type="text" ng-model="todoHashTag" size="50" placeholder="Tag">
  
  <input id="message" type="text" ng-model="todoMessage" size="50" placeholder="Message">
  
    <input id="butGetNew" type="submit" value="Add New"> <!--add new-->
</form>

<br>

<div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
  <span ng-bind="x.hashtag"></span>
  <span ng-bind="x.todoText"></span>
</div>

  
</body>
```

Comment: Какого характера тег? На каком языке сообщение?

Comment: Обычный хештег, как в инстаграме или твиттере. Английский

Comment: я так понимаю нужно реализовать что бы можно было писать несколько хэштегов?

Comment: Нет, лишь один. После пробела идет сообщение , которое записывается в отдельный массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
если только первое слово является хэштегом то можно так сделать например
```

```js
function cut()
{
  var message = $('#message').val();
  var count = message.indexOf(' '); //ищем первый пробел в сообщении
  var hashtag = message.substring(0, count); //отрезаем первое слово 
  if(hashtag[0] != '#') hashtag = '#' + hashtag;
  var text = message.substring(count, message.length); //отреаем все что после первого слова
  console.log('hashtag: ' + hashtag);
  console.log('message: ' + text);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<input type="button" onclick="cut()" value="Порезать"/>
```

Comment: Да! Именно то что нужно!
Спасибо огромное )

Comment: @endoneslife, спасибо тут выражается плюсом и, если решено, принятием ответа.